# How to instantiate a class with a private constructor using Laravel container

Tags: php, laravel, oop, testing

I have an API call class with a private constructor

```
private function __construct(
    private readonly string $apiArg1
    private readonly string $apiArg2
) {
}
```

I am trying to instantiate this class calling its static function `getInstance`

```
public static function getInstance(): self
{
    $args = self::getArgs();
    return app(self::class, ['apiArg1' => data_get($args, 'arg1'), 'apiArg2' => data_get($args, 'arg2')]);
}
```

But this returns `Target [Path\To\ApiClassName] is not instantiable` when calling `getInstance`

If I use `new self` instead it works, but then I am not sure how would I be able to use this class in tests where I would need to mock it

How should I approach this situation? Is there a way for me to make it work for tests using `new self` or is there something I am missing in regards to using `app()` in this situation?

Comment: You cannot have a private constructor

Comment: Actually you can if you want to force the user to use a different approach for getting a class instance. There's design patterns that depends on it like Singletons where you want to prevent to be instanced more than once...